Mathematica produces the diagonal minors in reverse order? Why?
For the matrix
L={{-k31-k32,k13,k23},{k31,-k12-k13,k21},{k32,k12,-k21-k23}};

Mathematica produces the reverse
Kv=Reverse[Diagonal[Minors[L]]]
(*Compute the minors for K1,K2,K3 by removing the corresponding row and column*)
detMi[L_,i_]:=Det[Delete[Delete[L,i]//Transpose,i]//Transpose];
K1={detMi[L,1],detMi[L,2],detMi[L,3]}
K1-Kv//Factor

of what I thought the diagonal minors are. Why?
Note that without Reverse, the fact that this vector is in the kernel is not true
L . Kv//Factor
L . Diagonal[Minors[L]]//Factor


Adjugate might be what you want. As for the ordering used by Minors, I think there is some explanation in the reference page (I cannot check right now).
